# Image type Python: loaded a jpg, showing a png

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have been playing around with images in Python, just trying to understand how things work basically. I have noticed something odd and was wondering if anyone else could explain it.

I have an image 'duck.jpg' - [image]

If I look at the properties I can see that it is a jpg image.

However, after importing into python using the follwoing convoluted way:

```
from PIL import Image
import io

with open('duck.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    im =  Image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
    f.close()
```

I get the following output after calling 
`im.format`

`'PNG'`

Is there some sort of automatic conversion going on?

[image]

Comment: I'm chacking this on my computer but the format won't change. Are you sure the image you are reading is a `jpeg`. The one you've uploaded is a `png` and I guess imgur won't change the image format.

Comment: I have uploaded an image of the result of right clicking the image and then inspecting. When I saaved the image to my local directory I put the suffic '.jpg' assuming this would save it as a jpg. Maybe this is not the case

Comment: I see. Tbh idk what's going on. It won't change for me and the official docs of Pillow don't mention any format modifications.

Comment: And BTW you don't need the `f.close()` there since you are using context manager.